# Vaadin visibility DOM Tree

Tags: java, dom, visibility, vaadin

**Question :** When you set a Layouts visibility it is either added to the DOM tree or removed from it. What does vaadin do with the removed part? Does it cach it or is it re-created once you set the visibility to show once again? And if its re-created does all its sub-components get re-attached as well?

The reason I ask is that when I hade a VerticalLayout with a form in it and the form it self hade use the below code i couldnt see my textfields that hade the size set to 100% when I went from layout.setVisible(true) -> false -> and show once again.

```
private Form getAttachedForm() {
    return new Form(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void attachField(Object propertyId, Field field){
            if(field instanceof TextField){
                TextField tf = (TextField)field;
                tf.setWidth("100%");
            }else if(field instanceof DateField){
                DateField df = (DateField)field;
                df.setResolution(DateField.RESOLUTION_DAY);
                df.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
            super.attachField(propertyId, field);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vaadin does not remove the elements from the DOM, but sets the `display` property (CSS) of the element(s). However, it seems that the sizing information is also deleted and there might be a bug causing the calculations not to be performed when making the components visible again.

A bug report at [dev.vaadin.com](http://dev.vaadin.com) would be much appreciated.